# Why does std::vector::operator= overallocate memory?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am investigating a case where way more memory is consumed than needed. If I assign a string to an `std::vector`, it suddenly reserves more heap memory than needed, even though the size of the string is already known:

Here's what I broke it down to:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

void* operator new(size_t size) { 
    void * p = malloc(size); 
    std::cout << "\talloc " << size << " @ " << p; 
    return p;
} 

void operator delete(void* p) { 
    std::cout << "\t      free " << p; 
    free(p);
} 

int main() {
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "1. Create first string:   ";
        auto s1 = std::string{"String with 20 chars"};

        std::cout << std::endl << "2. Create longer string:  ";
        auto s2 = std::string{"String with 25 characters"};

        std::cout << std::endl << "3. Copy construct:        ";
        auto s3 = s2;

        std::cout << std::endl << "4. Copy assign:           ";
        s1 = s3;

        std::cout << std::endl << "5. Leaving scope:         ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
1. Create first string:     alloc 21 @ 0x56047f176280
2. Create longer string:    alloc 26 @ 0x56047f1762a0
3. Copy construct:          alloc 26 @ 0x56047f1762d0
4. Copy assign:             alloc 41 @ 0x56047f176300         free 0x56047f176280
5. Leaving scope:                 free 0x56047f1762d0         free 0x56047f1762a0         free 0x56047f176300
```

I would expect line 4 to be the same as line 3.

**Why do both libstdc++ (this result) and libc++ (32/48 bytes) allocate more memory for a copy assignment than for a copy construction?** In both cases, the new size is known. I can't see how one of those is more likely to require additional memory in the future.

Comment: Virtual memory is cheap (in most cases free). Allocating memory doesn't cost you anything until someone uses that memory. Linux, for example, doesn't back any allocation with physical memory before someone writes. So, having 128GB allocated costs nothing if you only write to 1MB.

Comment: Fix your question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Sure, but that is a different scale. If every string costs you 41 instead of 26 bytes, that space will be committed as it is way smaller than a page. In my case (an in-memory database), this ended up wasting 300 MB on a data set of 1 GB.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I tracked it down in the basic_string implementation of libstdc++. `operator=(const basic_string&)` calls `this->assign`, which calls [`_M_assign`](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc.html#255), which calls [`_M_create`](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc.html#133) with the new (minimal) and the old capacity. Here, the original capacity is doubled. A link to the exponential growth policy is included as a comment.

First, I did not understand how this is related to my example. After all, I just want to replace a value.

The growth policy for `operator=(const basic_string&)` makes more sense when, instead of a single assignment, you consider this code:

```
std::string s;
for (auto i = 100; i < 110; ++i) s = s + std::to_string(i);
```

Here, setting the capacity so that it is "just fitting" would violate the linear growth requirement.

To solve the memory consumption problem, I now call `shrink_to_fit()` on the target string.